# FadeTo and SlideDown - Firefox Issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prepend the data then fade out the old div and slide down the new div. Works great in Chrome but in Firefix it will fade out the old div but not slide down new div. It will only slide down correctly in Firefox browser when data is cached in the browser.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code that could allow that to happen in Firefox? Thanks much...

**HTML**

```
<div class="Output">
   <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "file.php",
   timeout: 3000,
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(myhtml){

      var new_div = $(myhtml).hide();
      $(".Output").prepend(new_div);

      $(".block").fadeTo("normal", 0.00, function(){

         $(".block2").hide().slideDown('normal', function() {
         });

      });       

   }
});
```

**file.php**

```
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: If you are testing this on empty elements they have no width or height. Try putting some content or settings width in height in css. This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PvGjt/ works ok in ff.

Comment: I have content in there. Its not that

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the download of the content? is there something I can add that will wait for the content to load before sliding down?

Answer (score 0):

put the slide and fade in the `complete` callback.

see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

In your case, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "file.php",
   timeout: 3000,
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(myhtml){

      var new_div = $(myhtml).hide();
      $(".Output").prepend(new_div);

   },
   complete: function(){

         //you may need to check if the ajax result was actually a success here
         $(".block").fadeTo("normal", 0.00, function(){

            $(".block2").hide().slideDown('normal', function() {
            });

      });   
   }
});
```